# QtCreator: QML Debugger, connection refused - switch off QML debugger?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qml

In QtCreator (2.5.2, Win7) I get a permanent / repeating output in the Debugger window. Debugging etc. all fine. Since I do not need QML debugging, how can I switch off the QML debugger? Or fix the issue in order to get rid of the repeating message.

```
QML Debugger: Error: (0) Connection refused
QML Debugger: Connecting to debug server 127.0.0.1:3768
QML Debugger: resolving host...
QML Debugger: connecting to debug server...
```

Have tried `CONFIG -= declarative_debug` with no effect.

Screenshot:

[image: QML debugger message]

Comment: Try a clean and Rebuild. That might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Qt Creator, go to Projects mode, in Run Settings, go to Debugger Settings and uncheck Enable QML Debugging. This will disable QML debugging.

Comment: That's it. I have tried this, but in my case it only works only after the next rebuild and debug start - not immediately. Thanks.